# Problem in JStree and Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jstree

```
$("#treeDiv").dblclick(function () { 
    this.rename(this.data.ui.hovered || this.data.ui.last_selected); 
});
```

I am working on JSTree. And I tried the above code to rename the node of tree. 
`treeDiv` is the Id of div of tree. The above code is not working. Any body know the mistake where I did please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In above code this will be pointed to the  itself and not a jstree object nor a jquery object.

This is the correct form:

```
$("#treeDiv")
    .bind("dblclick.jstree", function (evnt) {
        $(this).jstree('rename', evnt.target);
    });
```

As a rule when you doesn't have the real jstree object (which support .rename) you should use `$('#tree').jstree(command, arg)` and also, you should use events like example above.